# No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._base'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data, imblearn

I have recently installed imblearn package in jupyter using

```
!pip show imbalanced-learn
```

But I am not able to import this package.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f19c5a0e54af> in <module>
      1 # from sklearn.utils import resample
      2 from tensorflow.keras import backend
----> 3 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
      4 
      5 

~/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/__init__.py in <module>
     32     Module which allowing to create pipeline with scikit-learn estimators.
     33 """
---> 34 from . import combine
     35 from . import ensemble
     36 from . import exceptions

~/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/combine/__init__.py in <module>
      3 """
      4 
----> 5 from ._smote_enn import SMOTEENN
      6 from ._smote_tomek import SMOTETomek
      7 

~/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/combine/_smote_enn.py in <module>
      8 from sklearn.utils import check_X_y
      9 
---> 10 from ..base import BaseSampler
     11 from ..over_sampling import SMOTE
     12 from ..over_sampling.base import BaseOverSampler

~/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/base.py in <module>
     14 from sklearn.utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets
     15 
---> 16 from .utils import check_sampling_strategy, check_target_type
     17 
     18 

~/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
      5 from ._docstring import Substitution
      6 
----> 7 from ._validation import check_neighbors_object
      8 from ._validation import check_target_type
      9 from ._validation import check_sampling_strategy

~/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imblearn/utils/_validation.py in <module>
     11 
     12 from sklearn.base import clone
---> 13 from sklearn.neighbors._base import KNeighborsMixin
     14 from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
     15 from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._base'
```

Other packages in the environment

```
numpy==1.16.2
pandas==0.24.2
paramiko==2.1.1
matplotlib==2.2.4
scikit-learn==0.22.1
Keras==2.2.4
tensorflow==1.12.0
tensorboard==1.12.0
tensorflow-hub==0.4.0
xlrd==1.2.0
flask==1.0.2
wtforms==2.2.1
bs4==0.0.1
gensim==3.8.1
spacy==2.2.3
nltk==3.4.5 
wordcloud==1.6.0
pymongo==3.10.1    
imbalanced-learn==0.6.1
```

I checked the sklearn package, it contains base module, not _base. But modifying it may not be the right solution. Any other solution to fix this issue.

Comment: `sklearn.neighbors._base` has been a thing since scikit-learn 0.22.1 (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/62aee0666e8803f20ecf0f6214621367e50f3961#diff-4ff1a647d9d4ef33358643ec58c914c7). Are you sure you're looking at the right environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Previous `sklearn.neighbors.base` has been renamed to `sklearn.neighbors._base` [in version 0.22.1](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/62aee0666e8803f20ecf0f6214621367e50f3961#diff-4ff1a647d9d4ef33358643ec58c914c7).
You have probably a version of scikit-learn older than that.
Installing the [latest release](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/releases) solves the problem:

`pip install -U scikit-learn`

or

`pip install scikit-learn==0.22.1`

Answer (score 18):

If in case you want to persist with the latest version of scikit-learn, add the following code to your script or execute the following code in your environment before installing imblearn

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
```

This has to be after

```
pip install sklearn
```

or in a notebook environment:

```
!pip install sklearn
```

This problem stems from the fact that certain modules are named with an underscore in the newer scikit-learn releases

Comment: Worked for me, I was getting the error `No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base'` (in sklearn version 0.24.1) when importing `missingpy`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem trying to import SMOTE from `imblearn.over_sampling` and my version of scikit-learn was up to date (0.24.1). What worked for me was:

First I downgraded my scikit learn version to 0.22.1 using

```
 pip install scikit-learn==0.22.1
```

Next, I updated the imbalanced-learn package using:

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

That uninstalled scikit-learn-0.22.1, installed the updated version (scikit-learn-0.24.1), and updated the imbalanced-learn package. Everything worked fine thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a particular env, you must copy the `_base` file or `base` file to the env from package file.

I had the same problem in my tensorflow env. I just copied `_base` and `base` file to my tensorflow env and worked.