# ImportError: cannot import name 'clone' from 'sklearn.neighbors._base

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

while doing

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss
```

I got error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base'
```

After going through the SO thread [No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._base'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145652/no-module-named-sklearn-neighbors-base) , I changed code to below:

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
```

Now I got error below

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'clone' from 'sklearn.neighbors._base' (/home/userr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py)
```

scikit version is 1.0.2

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn. __version__)
```

Comment: I have downgraded my imblearn to 0.6, then its started working

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the respective package,
firstly you need to install the below:-

1. pip install sklearn (this might change based on your tool or environment and also choose the apt version for your tool and code)

then, import the below 2 statements in your code,

2)
import sklearn.neighbors._base

sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base

hope, this helps you