# MissForest: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import the MissForest library and I'm getting an error in sklearn.neighbors.base

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base '] = sklearn.neighbors._base

from missingpy import MissForest
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.base'
```

Comment: Did the error happen on the import statement?  On the assignment to `sys.modules`?  Don't make us guess.  Post the full error traceback message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.\_base'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145652/no-module-named-sklearn-neighbors-base)

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your issue.
According to the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/epsilon-machine/missingpy/blob/master/requirements.txt) for `missingpy`, the version of `scikit-learn` you need is 0.20.1. Unfortunately, that version won't easily install on any version of python later than version 3.8. If you happen to be on 3.8 or earlier, all you have to do is go to your command line and run

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==0.20.1
```

Once you have the right version, you won't need to do any craziness with renaming modules. You can just do this:

```
import sklearn.neighbors.base
import missingpy
```

However, downgrading your environment to an earlier version of python just to use a single library isn't always a great idea. Look into other options for your specific use case and see if you can find a more modern solution than `missingpy`.
In summary, if you really need to use `missingpy`, your procedure is:

1. Rollback your python version to 3.8 (if needed)
2. Rollback your `scikit-learn` version to 0.20.1
3. Import your modules (in order)

Answer (score 0):

To unistall:  `py -m pip install -U scikit-learn`

`py -m pip install scikit-learn`. Was released Released: Feb 16, 2024

```
py -m pip show scikit-learn
```